# Destination location when using ADD command if <dest> is not provided

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to push my application from local to a network Linux server. I have the Dockerfile like this

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/approot
ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]
```

According to the [document,](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> If `<dest>` doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.

I don't understand it. What is the physical path of the destination? Because I thought that there was a folder `/app` somewhere on the network server but I could not locate it.

Comment: A Docker container is like a virtual machine, it has its own file system. `/app` would be inside the container. On the Linux server, you can login to the container using `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash` to see what's inside

Comment: @warmoverflow, I run your command. It just hanging there. I have SSH client to touch the Linux server. Is there a place to hold that information? Example `/var/lib` something like?

Comment: Is the container already running on your server? If so, after you SSH login to the server, run `docker ps` to get the id of the container, and then run `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash` to login to the container.

Comment: @warmoverflow, I stopped it but the container exists there. I used `ps -a`. Oops, perhaps I deleted the image.

Comment: You cannot login to a stopped container. The folder will be inside but you cannot login and see it. If you only want to verify, you can export the container as a `tar` file and see what's inside, use `docker export container_id > archive.tar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the clue, it might be useful. [Where are Docker images stored?](http://blog.thoward37.me/articles/where-are-docker-images-stored/)

Where is this stuff? The first place to look is in `/var/lib/docker/`

Checkout what's in `/var/lib/docker/graph/`.
So what's actually stored there?
The entries here are:

- json - holds metadata about the image
- layersize - just a number, indicating the size of the layer
- layer/ - sub-directory that holds the rootfs for the container image